# HTMLDocument css html conflict

Tags: java, css, swing, font-size, dom

I'm facing an issue with the way Swing manage CSS in HTMLDocument, font-size in particular :

if i do :

```
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(jtextPane.getInputAttributes(), 15);
```

then,

```
    StyleConstants.getFontSize(jtextPane.getInputAttributes()));
```

will return 18...

I discovered that this may be because of the method :

```
    fromStyleConstants(StyleConstants key, Object value)
```

from CSS.java, that converts the parameter value into the higher value of the following Array :
        static final int sizeMapDefault[] = { 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 24, 36 };
from the class StyleSheet

But in this case, why sometimes I get 18 and sometimes I get 15... I was wondering if it could not come from a conflict between HTML and CSS attributes. Actually, when I check the StyleConstants.fontSize attribute worth 15, but I have a CSS.Attribute.font-size attribute that may generate a conflict ?

Otherwise, if I load the html :

```
    <html><body><p style="font-size:2em;">test</p></body></html>
```

The text is correctly displayed. But then, I set the caret between the "e" and the "s", and then check all the attributes (characterElement, paragraph, input, etc). The font-size is always 12... What am I supposed to do to get the correct value ?

To conclude, is there a way to get and set the value of font-size with something more trustable than StyleConstants.setFontSize ?